# Custom relationship result labels in Laravel Administrator (frozennode)

Tags: php, laravel, nested, administrator

I have a three level structure like Category » Subcategory » Product.

Using Frozennode's Laravel Administrator, I'm trying to make it so that when I create or edit a product, my subcategory relationship shows something like:

- Category1 » Subcategory1
- Category1 » Subcategory2
- ...

Currently I'm trying to override the query of products.php in this way:

```
    'subcategory' => [
        'title' => 'Category tree',
        'type' => 'relationship',
        'name_field' => 'tree',
        'options_filter' => function($query) {

            $str = 'select CONCAT(cat.name, " » ", sc.name) as tree, 
            cat.id, cat.name, sc.id, sc.name
                    from categories cat
                    inner join subcategories sc on sc.category_id = cat.id';

            $query = \DB::table('subsubcategories')->select(\DB::raw($str));

            return $query;
        }
    ],
```

However this outputs a blank result set in Administrator's dropdown, I'm guessing because 'tree' doesn't really exist as a valid name_field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.